# CDbl and decimal separators in VB .NET - Is there a way to bypass Regional Settings?

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, parsing

I am writing a program that parses and manipulates information (text and numbers) from Excel sheets. I am facing a weird problem regarding converting a cell data to a Double variable. Most of the time, and thanks to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel import, I use:

```
var = CDbl(sheet.Cells(row,column).Value)
```

However, my sheet (which consists of thousands of rows) contains decimal numbers written with both "." and ",". In my country, "," is considered as decimal separator, so any number like "1.23456789" raises an exception from CDbl.

I have found a workaround, which consists of using not the .Value but the .Text of the cell, and use a Replace() to get rid of the ".":

```
var = CDbl(sheet.Cells(row,column).Text.Replace(".", ","))
```

However, this increases my execution time greatly, due to the length of the sheets I'm manipulating. What would be the quickest way to do this? Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to get rid of the Regional Settings and consider "." and "," alike? Any other suggestions?

Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corrrect way is to use [`double.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447(v=vs.110).aspx)(or `decimal.Parse`) with the correct culture or `NumberFormatInfo`. You could for example use german culture:

```
Dim deCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE")
Dim number = Double.Parse(sheet.Cells(row,column).Text, deCulture)
```

If the input can be invalid you should use [`Double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But unfortunately, while this solution doesn't raise exceptions anymore, "." are completely erased, which converts a decimal to an integer ("1.2345" becomes "12345"). What I would like is both "," and "." to be considered as decimal separators.

Comment: @user7831458: but you wrote: _"In my country, "," is considered as decimal separator,"_ Why you now say that you also want to treat thousand-group separators as decimal separators? What's with a number `1.234.567,89`? Perfectly valid, it is the same as `1234567,89`

Comment: In the Excel sheets, which is edited by several people in the company I work in, some people write "." and others use "," for decimal separation. I wanted to avoid editing the Excel files due to their length. But what I'm sure of is that no thousand-group separator is ever used. :)

Comment: This column should have a number format, then no one can enter invalid values. How you diffferentiate `123,456` from `123.456`. The first could mean `123.456` and the second `123456` or vice versa. The answer is: you simply don't know what it is. You are asking for a programmatic way to determine an information that is simply not available. What prevents the user from entering `1.234,99` or `1,234.99`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `CDbl`, that's simply a remnant of older VB dialects which doesn't allow you to change the number format it's using; it assumes your computer's current culture.  Instead, use .NET's more powerful `Double.Parse` method which allows you to provide the culture.

As Tim points out, you can use cultures to specify the group and decimal separators.  In your case, though, since you have mixed formats, you'll need to recognize which is which somehow, and for this you can use regular expressions.

I'll borrow Tim's German culture for my example, and use US for the opposite format:

```
Dim test1 = "12,342,123.2323"
Dim test2 = "122.222.636,22"
Dim toTest = test1
Dim output As Double
Dim usCulture = New CultureInfo("en-US")
Dim deCulture = New CultureInfo("de-DE")

If (Regex.IsMatch(toTest, "^(\d{1,3}\,)*\d{3}\.\d+$")) Then
    output = Double.Parse(toTest, usCulture)
ElseIf (Regex.IsMatch(toTest, "^(\d{1,3}\.)*(\d{3})\,\d+$")) Then
    output = Double.Parse(toTest, deCulture)
End If
```